# coresponding curl command for ajax call

Tags: ajax, curl

I have a website that is doing the auth as follows:

- you click a Login button that triggers a javascript function which shows an existing form marked as hidden. This means that the form cannot be submitted directly with a POST webrequest (this worked on another site, but not on this one)
- when submitting the form another javascript function is triggered that calls an AJAX call to /ajax/login

Javascript functions:

```
ajax: function() {
    if (!Login.blocked) {
        Login.blocked = true;
        var fields = Login.getFormData();
        ajax('/ajax/login', Login.getResponse, Login.packData(fields));
    }
    packData: function(obj) {
            var data = [];
            for (key in obj) {
                data.push(key + '=' + obj[key]);
            }
```

Tampered data:

```
Host=*********
User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Accept=*/*
Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br
X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer=https://*********/
Content-Length=105
Cookie=utc=0918a5d99a7; _ga=GA1.2.1988660761.1492530049; __gads=ID=4db40c28b6af8254:T=1492530048:S=ALNI_MYCC-8HnoEW3ecRExG9wg9AA9b9mw; XSRF-TOKEN=************************************; _gid=GA1.2.41413306.1493735447; surveymonkey=true; SRV=s2; acceptcookies=true
Connection=keep-alive
POSTDATA=_token=*********&email=*********%40gmail.com&password=*********&=Authentication
```

The token that is being sent is part of the login form and it is generated automatically when the page is accessed:

> input name="_token" type="hidden"
>   value="rpt8UZiKGq8ARRvDVEZslU9erqT7Xzmv35F2QjxN"

I'm using cURL to test and I've been through like 100 tries with no result. Doing "--dump-header cookie.txt" to check the result each time.

Examples:

```
curl --dump-header cookie.txt -d "_token=4l8bOObleRsquW******&email=******%40gmail.com&password=******&=Authentication" -H "Contenty-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://*******/ajax/login/

-H "Contenty-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 

-H "Accept:*/*" -H "X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest"

-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"

-H "Accept: application/json"
```

Also tried the format `{"email":"******@gmail.com","password":"******"}` for data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@for anyone wondering

The token needed was actually in a httponly cookie so even if I would've succeeded I had no guarantee that curl was able to capture that cookie.

To work-around this issue I have done IE automation in powershell using COM InternetExplorer.Application, logged in to the site, extracted the token from the cookie file on disk, constructed a cookie object in powershell, added it to a websession and invoking webrequests/restrequests using that websession (all in powershell).

I never close IE (visible = $false), refresh it every few minutes (even that the page has a keep alive) and renew the token from disk.

-Dizzy